# Convergence of a monotone increasing sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So here is the question. There is a **real** number $\beta$. Show that there exists a *monotone increasing sequence* of **rational numbers** which converges to $\beta$. I don't understand how to start the proof. I need to show that $\beta$ is the *supremum* of the sequence such that it converges to $\beta$. So can someone explain how should I go about proving this? Also, can this proof be modified to suit a monotone increasing sequence of irrational nos. as well?
This is my approach- Suppose I consider a sequence {an} (monotone increasing) which has the supremum= $\beta$. Thus, an<=$\beta$ for all n in **N**. Thus, for some *N*, $\epsilon$+a*N*> $\beta$. Also, by denseness, we always have rational nos. in (aN,$\beta$). Thus, for this *N*>**N**(natural numbers), (beta-an)>$\epsilon$, thus satisfying convergence at $\beta$. Can someone say if this is a rigorous enough proof?

Comment: Use the fact that any interval contains both a rational number and an irrational number.

Comment: I did think of denseness, but can you please state on what note should I start my proof(that is, if i start with a contradiction, what should be my statement?)

Comment: You say there are rational numbers in $(a_n,\beta)$ but it's not clear how this leads to a monotonically increasing sequence of rational numbers.  You need to pick rational numbers in $(a_n, a_{n+1})$

Comment: Ok...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Define:

- $A_n = \{k/2^n \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$
- $a_n = \sup A_n \cap \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \lt \beta\}$
- $b_n = \sup\{a_k \mid 1\le k \le n\}$

$\{b_n\}$ is a possible sequence you're looking for.

And if you're looking for a sequence of irrational numbers, replace $A_n$ with $A_n^\prime = \{k \sqrt 2/2^n \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct the sequence.  There's a rational number $\beta_1$ in the interval $(\beta-1, \beta)$.  There's a rational number $\beta_2$ in the interval $(\beta_1,\beta)$ and so on.  Construct a sequence of irrationals in a similar way.

Comment: If i construct a sequence {an}(monotone increasing) such that supremum is beta, then an<=beta. Then for some n(in natural numbers), an+epsilon>beta. Also by denseness, there are rational numbers between an and beta. So for all n>=N, (beta-an)>epsilon, this satisfying convergence at beta. Can you comment if this is a rigorous enough proof?

Comment: You should add this to the body of your question.  It's not appropriate as a comment on my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll be adding it. Can you just say if it's good enough?

Comment: Ok, I've done it. Can you check it now?